# Overheating of my laptop?

Tags: 20.04, lenovo, overheating, tlp

I am using a Lenovo Ideapad with a core i5 10th gen and nvidia mx250 graphics, dual booting Ubuntu 20.04LTS

I don’t know why, but my laptop is overheating and I have tried using `tlp` but there is no difference in the device.
Can anyone help me this issue ?

Comment: Start [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1260698/high-cpu-temp-on-boot-fan-noise-on-ubuntu-thinkpad-t490/1260716#1260716).

Comment: Could it be that your laptop's cooling is clogged up with dust and debris?  Is the fan working properly? Does this problem occur if you boot to a different operating system using your dual-boot?  If you run 'top' can you see what is pegging your CPU most?

Comment: @DavidO When i boot to windows everything run fine. My laptop is hardly 1 month old, so I think fans are not clogged up with dust ! My battery is also draining too quickly in ubuntu

Comment: You answered three of my four questions. What does 'top' tell you is consuming CPU?

Comment: it is `systemd+`